# Free Heroku plan and TLS certificate

Tags: node.js, heroku, tls1.3

I know if I upgrade to the Hobby Plan (7$ for month) I can have it automatically.

But is there any way to set TLS certificate on Heroku free plan and how?

I'm use node js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem in the past so I can give you a short answer: Use cloudflare free plan. Open a free account in cloudflare, Copy the DNS. Then set the DNS in your domain service provider (godaddy or sth), then change the Cname config for the website inside cloudflare. Now you have a free certificate!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to set TLS certificate on an app running on free dynos unfortunately...
From the heroku site, you need to upgrade your application to at least a Hobby plan (7$ for month) to use it  :
[heroku-ACM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSDhQ.jpg)